# How to detect when user zooms in on web application

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have web application that uses Bootstrap and media queries to adjust popups and sizes and such. But now I am at a wall when it comes to when a user zooms in, say to 125% from 100%, and some of the app scales ok, but not everything. So my question is how do you detect when a browser is zoomed in and adjust accordingly from that point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: @VaibhavVishal, that links helps out alot. Thanks

Comment: The link showed me how to detect the zooming in, which is awesome. But with that how do you adjust the size of a div based on the zoom in? if the page is normally at 100% and a popup is say 500px wide and 400px high and looks fine in the 100% but if you zoom at 125% how do you then adjust the size of the popup so it looks normal in that zoom

Comment: Don't adjust, when people zoom in, they want things to get bigger. Why would want to keep it same size. If you really want that, use `vw`/`vh`